# Validity of the expression $\operatorname{arccot}(\cot(\pi k))=0$ by extending the definition to evaluate at discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, continuity, infinity

I'm exploring the properties and behaviors of trigonometric functions, specifically the cotangent function $\cot(\pi x) $ and its behavior near its discontinuities. The normal domain of $\cot(x)$ excludes integer multiples of $\pi$, where the function is traditionally undefined due to the sine function being zero:

$$
x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{k\pi \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$

At these points, $x = k\pi$, the function approaches negative or positive infinity depending on the direction of the approach:

$$
\lim_{{x \to k\pi^+}} \cot(\pi x) = -\infty \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{{x \to k\pi^-}} \cot(\pi x) = +\infty
$$

From this, we can see that as $x$ approaches $+\infty$, the angle $\theta$ whose cotangent is $x$ must approach $0$:

$$
\lim_{{x \to +\infty}} \operatorname{arccot}(x) = 0
$$

Considering this, I'm curious if this expression is accurate in context:

$$\operatorname{arccot}(\cot(\pi k))=0$$

Normally, we would consider $\cot(\pi k)$ undefined for integer $k$. However, if we were to extend the definition to infinity at these points, it seems we could argue that $\operatorname{arccot}(\cot(\pi k)) = 0$.

Comment: For integer $k$, the expression $\mathrm{arccot}(\cot(\pi k))$ is undefined. You may extend the definition by setting $\mathrm{arccot}(\cot(\pi k)) = 0$. This way, the function becomes continuous from the right at all reals, but not continuous from the left. But you can also extend the definition by setting $\mathrm{arccot}(\cot(\pi k)) = \pi$ and the function becomes continuous from the left, but not from the right. Then why to choose one extension over the other?

Comment: My goal is to establish a mathematical identity involving the floor function ⌊x⌋. 

Specifically, I want to show that ⌊x⌋= πx−arccot(cot(πx)) / π

To prove this, I propose that the expression arccot(cot(πx)) can be equated to mod(πx, π).

The reasoning behind this extension is that arccot(cot(πx)) should give us an angle within the principal range [0, π) that is coterminal with πx. In other words, 
arccot(cot(πx)) should be the unique angle in [0, π) that πx reduces to when considering it modulo.